# Setting maxlength using database schema settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a good way to set maxlength on input tags using the corresponding limits from the database schema?  I can always check the database lengths for fields, and then hard code the maxlength values, but I would prefer not to have those settings in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to rails api docs [TableDefinition#column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) :limit suits your needs